# Passing 'this' and argument to addEventListener function without using bind

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-restartless

Subsequent to [removeEventListener in bootstrapped addon not working when addon disabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24470716/removeeventlistener-in-bootstrapped-addon-not-working-when-addon-disabled/24470756#24470756), I am exploring other possibilities.

Beside using `bind()` and caching the bound function, is there a way to use 'this' and pass argument?

```
// works fine but can't pass argeement
contextMenu.addEventListener('popupshowing', 
     this.contextPopupShowing, false);

// passes the argument but 'this' is no longer available
contextMenu.addEventListener('popupshowing', 
    function(){this.contextPopupShowing(window);}, false);
```

I have been using a number of event listeners with `bind()` and I am looking for alternative methods without using `bind()`

I even tried to grab `window` with a recursive function from `<menupopup id="contentAreaContextMenu" ...>`

**Update:** `bind()` interferes with `removeEventListener`

Comment: What's wrong with using `.bind()` to connect up the right `this` with your method?  This is exactly what it's for.  There are other work-arounds, but none are as clean as `.bind()`.

Comment: Thank you jfriend00. As mentioned, the interference of `bind` with `removeEventListener`

Comment: Your combination of wanting to use `.removeEventListener()` and control the `this` ptr in your function means you HAVE to both create a stub function to pass to `.addEventListener()` and remember that stub function for use with `.removeEventListener()`.  There isn't any alternative.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since we're talking restartless add-ons... A lot of restartless add-ons use `unload` and `unloadWindow` helper functions, to make it easier to implement `shutdown` properly and also help with stuff like `addEventListener`, so bear with me for a bit.

### The helpers - `unload`

First, `unload` is a helper function that you pass another function to, that will be run upon `shutdown` (or can be called manually). Most implementations are extremely similar to this:

```
var unloaders = []; // Keeps track of unloader functions.

function unload(fn) {
  if (typeof(fn) != "function") {
    throw new Error("unloader is not a function");
  }
  unloaders.push(fn);
  return function() {
    try {
      fn();
    }
    catch (ex) {
      Cu.reportError("unloader threw " + fn.toSource());
      Cu.reportError(ex);
    }
    unloaders = unloaders.filter(function(c) { return c != fn; });
  };
}
```

You'd then hook up `shutdown` to do the right thing:

```
function shutdown() {
  ...
  for (let i = unloaders.length - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
    try {
      unloaders[i]();
    }
    catch (ex) {
      Cu.reportError("unloader threw on shutdown " + fn.toSource());
      Cu.reportError(ex);
    }
  }
  unloaders.length = 0;
}
```

### Using `unload`

Now you can do stuff like:

```
function startup() {
  setupSomething();
  unload(removeSomething);

  setupSomethingElse();
  var manualRemove = unload(removeSomethingElse);
  ...
  if (condition) {
    manualRemove();
  }
}
```

### The helpers - `unloadWindow`

You'll usually want to create a second function `unloadWindow` to unload stuff when either your add-on is shut down or the window gets closed, whatever happens first. Not removing stuff when the window gets closed can be very tricky, and create [Zombie compartments](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Zombie_compartments) of your `bootstrap.js` and/or code modules very easily (this is from experience writing and reviewing restartless add-ons).

```
function unloadWindow(window, fn) {
  let handler = unload(function() {
    window.removeEventListener('unload', handler, false);
    try {
      fn();
    }
    catch (ex) {
      Cu.reportError("window unloader threw " + fn.toSource());
      Cu.reportError(ex);
    }
  });
  window.addEventListener('unload', handler, false);
};
```

(Some people might want to "optimize" this, as to have only one `"unload"` handler, but usually you only have so `unloadWindow` calls that it won't matter.)

### Putting it all together

Now you can `.bind` stuff and do whatever and let the the unloader closures keep track of it. Also, you can use this to keep your shut down code next to your initialization code, which might increase readability.

```
function setupWindow(window, document) {
  var bound = this.contextPopupShowing.bind(this);
  contextMenu.addEventListener('popupshowing', bound, false);
  unloadWindow(window, function() {
    contextMenu.removeEventListener('popupshowing', bound, false);
  });

  // Or stuff like
  var element = document.createElement(...);
  contextMenu.appendChild(element);
  unloadWindow(window, function() {
    contextMenu.removeChild(element);
  });

  // Or just combine the above into a single unloader
  unloadWindow(window, function() {
    contextMenu.removeEventListener('popupshowing', bound, false);
    contextMenu.removeChild(element);
  });
}
```

Comment: Thank you Nils. I understood the caching of bound functions. I wrote a **tiny** restartless addon to familiarize myself (no pref, no XUL, simple contextmenu search) which is working fine. It has 4 event listeners. I can bind & cache them (creating 4 new variables & 4 new functions) which practically doubles the size of the addon (in memory). I wanted to make sure there are no other (better) ways of doing it before adopting that approach. :)

Comment: Yeah, I don't know what you're planning, but the extra memory to use and keep bound functions around is usually negligible unless you have tons of these and are on mobile. But if you got tons of these, you'll run into performance problems anyway. ;) E.g. a single github repo page I have open right now consumes about the same amount of memory as all my add-ons combined, and that includes Adblock Plus with their huge filter lists.

Comment: Gracious........ I'm actually new to binding I did for first time here: [GitHub :: Noitidart / HiliteOnSelection](https://github.com/Noitidart/HiliteOnSelection). This is an exceptional post man, thanks. I didn't know they were real helper functions for this.

Comment: I am unclear about unloaders. I am going to put it in a separate question.

Comment: I was to hasty this morning when I posted and simplified code too much. It is better to call unloaders in reverse order. Edited to change that.

Comment: Can you please explain this to me `unloaders = unloaders.filter(function(c) { return c != fn; });` First time I'm exploring `filter`

Comment: @Noitidart Just keep the items where the item is not `fn`, i.e. filter out any items that are `fn`. So it is just removing all instances of `fn` from the array.

Comment: I was trying to find bugs in your code cuz u always find bugs in mine and I couldnt. I thought I caught u leaving `unloader`s in the `unloaders` array after window close *and then* I caught you not `filter`ing out `unloader`s when it shouldn't be, like after a window close. But no man. But no. Anyways I learned a ton and plan to implement this. For people that need further explanation on it see here: [GitHubGIST ::  Noitidart / _ff-addon-tutorial-BootstrapUnloaderHelperFuncs.md #The-Helpers-Explained-Futher](https://gist.github.com/Noitidart/9d612a2eaa7bef5589e5#the-helpers-explained-further)

Comment: Hi @nmaier I think I found a point of concern, not an issue, just concern. Say the add-on is installed, and i added a bunch of unload functions with `unloadWindow`. Now if addon is uninstalled/disabled or window is closed it will run that unload function. However if Firefox is quit, this causes windows `unload` event to trigger right? I'm not sure if it is triggering. On quit of Firefox I don't want to run my unloaders as it will slow down shutdown of browser process as the whole browser is being torn down.

Answer (score 2):

Before `bind()` was supported you had to save a reference to `this` outside the function. Then pass in a function that can forward the invocation the way you want.

```
var self = this;
contextMenu.addEventListener('popupshowing', function() {
     self.contextPopupShowing.apply(self, arguments);
}, false);
```

In this case we use `apply` to set the context to `self`, our saved version of `this`, and to send it whatever `arguments` were passed to the anonymous function via the magic `arguments` keyword that contains the list of arguments that a function was passed when invoked.

Comment: Thank you Alex. Does `apply` (or `call`) interfere with `removeEventListener` the same way that `bind` does?

Comment: PS. Someone says at [addEventListener using apply()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2891096/addeventlistener-using-apply) that: *"it won't have the apply and call functions on it as properties"*!?

Comment: This doesn't allow the OP to call `removeEventListener()` on the event handler which is apparently a requirement.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to use `bind` for `addEventListener`. You can use `handleEvent`. It was in that topic I linked you too:

[Removing event listener which was added with bind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11565471/removing-event-listener-which-was-added-with-bind/23403134#23403134)

[MDN :: EventTarget.addEventListener - The value of "this" within the handler](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener#The_value_of_this_within_the_handler)

`handleEvent` is actually a common way the javascript code in the firefox codebase does it.

Copied straight from MDN:

```
var Something = function(element) {
  this.name = 'Something Good';
  this.handleEvent = function(event) {
    console.log(this.name); // 'Something Good', as this is the Something object
    switch(event.type) {
      case 'click':
        // some code here...
        break;
      case 'dblclick':
        // some code here...
        break;
    }
  };

  // Note that the listeners in this case are this, not this.handleEvent
  element.addEventListener('click', this, false);
  element.addEventListener('dblclick', this, false);

  // You can properly remove the listners
  element.removeEventListener('click', this, false);
  element.removeEventListener('dblclick', this, false);
}
```

Where I mostly use `bind` is when doing a `for` loop and I make anonymous functions with something in the array like `arr[i]`. If I don't bind it then it always just takes the last element of the array, I have no idea why, and I hate it, so then I go to using `[].forEach.call(arr, function(arrI)`.

Comment: I read that but it was unclear to me. The element is in `window` therefore does that mean that `handleEvent` listens to ALL window events in `window.addEventListener('click', this, false);`? There are other event listeners that need to go elsewhere.

Comment: No but anything that does `el.addEventListener('click', this, false)` will get routed through that. Where `this` is the `window` scope. But why attach on window man, try to go with JSM modules. Bootstrapped addons are a scope of its own so just put your stuff in there.

Comment: I guess you can also do `el.addEventListener('click', window, false)` notice the `window` in place of `this`

Comment: Thank you Noitidart. I am trying out `handleEvent` to catch all events and redirect accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

http://2ality.com/2013/06/auto-binding.html

```
var listener = myWidget.handleClick.bind(myWidget);
domElement.addEventListener('click', listener);
...
domElement.removeEventListener(listener);
```